# Azure NLB redirection is resulting in AntiForgery Exception upon load distribution

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

While using Microsoft Azure Services I have setup my UAT environment as follows:

- 2 - VMs with same configuration running on Window Server 2012 -> For
  MVC (FrontEnd)
- 2 - VMs with same configuration running on Window
  Server 2012 -> For API (Backend)
- 2 separate NLBs for both of these machines to distribute the loads evenly between the designated VMs

The API one works fine no issue on that but on the MVC whenever the request of single user is redirected to machine 2 from machine 1 it always results in Ant forgery Exception and I am forced to sign out and sign in again. This happens in alternate case as well when the request is redirected from VM2 to VM1.

Things I have tried and still no success:

- I have tried setting up SharedSession for the machines to keys from a common shared file which I placed on the primary server (VM1)
- In the above I tried placing the SharedSession key on both the VMs in case it get's an issue but still no resolution
- I have tried setting up user generated machine keys on IIS with custom settings and it still won't work

Comment: simple studip question: both machines are configured with the same machine key, right?

Comment: Yes they are. I have fixed the machine key myself on both configuration files along with IIS.